# tree list in a table

Tags: tables, lists, trees, dirtree

I would like to put a tree list into a table environment. Smth. like:

```
+--------------------------+---------------------------+-------------+
| Heading 1                |  Heading 2                | Heading 3   |
+--------------------------+---------------------------+-------------+
| / main-item              |  main item data           | some info   |
|   +-- sub item 1         |  sub item 1 data          | some info 1 |
|   |   +-- sub sub item x |  sub sub item 1.x data    | some info x |
|   |                      |                           |             |
|   +-- sub item 2         |  sub item 2 data          | some info 2 |
|       +-- sub sub item y |  sub sub item 2.y data    | some info y |
+--------------------------+---------------------------+-------------+
```

I know about dirtree package, but it it possible to arrange dirtree data in that way?

***P.S.: I received multiple answers to this question, which solve the problem. I personally found the accepted answer more appropriate in my case. But here are also answers how to achieve the requested functionality with dirtree package. Therefore I encourage everyone to read all answers to find the best possible solution.***

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Note that you don't have to (and shouldn't) sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: Related question: [Adding vertical hierarchy lines to a category column of a table.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195523/adding-vertical-hierarchy-lines-to-a-category-column-of-a-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here an example how you can mimic that with pure table environment. But you don't have connections between sub-items.

Hope that helps anyway.

```
\begin{table}[p]
\begin{center}
    \caption{Some caption of your table} \label{tab:trendtable}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \midrule[1pt]
    \multicolumn{1}{c} {Heading 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Heading 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c} {Heading 3} \\ 
    \midrule[1pt]
    \textbf{main-item}             & main item data        & some info\\
    \hspace{0.2cm} sub item 1      & sub item 1 data       & some info 1 \\
    \hspace{0.4cm} sub sub item x  & sub item 1.x          & some info x \\
    &&\\
    \textbf{main-item 2}           & ...                   & ...\\
    \hspace{0.2cm} ...             & ...                   & ... \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

[image: compiled code as an image]

Comment: While this seems to have been accepted by the questioner, it doesn't use `dirtree`, and since the answer posted by Yiannis (along with my comment) actually solves the problem with `dirtree` it should be preferred as an answer.

Comment: @Alan: Please see my comment in the post of Yiannis, regarding your answer. IMO this answer deserves a + point!

Comment: Instead `multicolumn{1}{c} {Heading 2}` it should be `\multicolumn{1}{c} {Heading 2}`!

Answer (score 8):

You can use `dirtree` within a table, just enclose the mark-up within a minipage and be careful with the stops at the end of the lines! Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{dirtree}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\begin{minipage}{4cm}\dirtree{%
.1 Engineering.
.2 Mechanical.
.3 Electrical.
.4 Electronics.
}\end{minipage}    
& \begin{minipage}{4cm}\dirtree{%
.1 TeX.
.2 LaTeX.
.3 XeTeX.
.4 pdfLaTeX.
}\end{minipage}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Image of first code]

**Edit as per comments**

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|p{3cm}|}
\begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}\dirtree{%
.1 Engineering.
.2 Mechanical.
.3 Electrical.
.4 Electronics.
}\end{minipage}    
&  Director A  
   \newline Director B 
   \newline Director C
   \newline Director D\\
\end{tabular}
```

This will produce an output as requested (two columns) the third is trivial! For anything more fancy I would use a graphics package such as `TikZ` or `pstricks`. This sort of layout IMHo is better produced using, just minipages and or specially constructed environments. Nevertheless `dirtree` is a great package and one can use it for all sorts of different problems.

[image: image of second code]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But unfortunately that example generates 2 dirtrees side-by-side. I would like to have just usual data associated with each dirtree item, but this data should be aligned in the table. It is possible that I might have 3 or more columns. You can think of it as some kind of a TreeListView control: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/treelistview.aspx

Comment: @Dusha: Make an extra `\dirtree`  for each of your subsequent columns, and use `\DTsetlength` with everything set to 0. (or if you still want indenting for the levels, set the width parameter.)

Comment: Alan thanks a lot. I did not explicitly require to use dirtree. I just stated that I know about that package. Anyway I find the accepted answer easier to use and maintain. It is more visual to have related items on one line, instead of counting the lines of subsequent dirtrees just to find out the relation. If you gave a minus point to the accepted answer, I find it a petty, since I really like the simplicity of the idea.

Comment: @dusha: Well, I can't argue with which you think answers your question, but your accepted solution also requires a lot of hand spacing, which is probably hard to maintain too. If others who do want to use `dirtree` in this way arrive at your question, they may think there is no solution using it if the accepted answer doesn't use it.

Comment: @Yiannis: I've put a full example as an answer for completeness.

Comment: @Alan: I will edit my question, to point out that here are multiple possible answers. I accepted the answer which seemed to be more appropriate in my case, but users should read following answers as well, just to be sure they find the best possible alternative.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a direct solution (based entirely off of Yiannis's answer) which solves the problem.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{dirtree,array}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c} {Heading 1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|} {Heading 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Heading 3}\\
\hline
\begin{minipage}{4cm}\dirtree{%
.1 Engineering.
.2 Mechanical.
.3 Bio-mechanical.
.2 Electronics.
}\end{minipage}
&
\DTsetlength{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\begin{minipage}{6cm}\dirtree{%
.1 Stuff about engineering here.
.2 Stuff about Mechanical here.
.3 Stuff about biomechanical here.
.4 .
}\end{minipage}
&
\DTsetlength{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\begin{minipage}{4cm}\dirtree{%
.1 Comments.
.2 More comments.
.3 Still more.
.4 And more.
}\end{minipage}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
&
\DTsetlength{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\begin{minipage}{6cm}\dirtree{%
.1 Stuff about engineering here.
.2 Stuff about Mechanical here.
.3 Stuff about Electrical here.
.4 .
}\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Image of compiled code]

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer using `\DTsetlength`, it is a very clean solution and programmabel, i.e one can define `\addline{}` and do a row etc that can work on both sides.