# Collapse table columns to vertical hierarchy

Tags: tables, pst-node

In constructing a table in LaTeX, I am exporting data from Excel with a hierarchical representation, but for more optimal printing I need to collapse the first four columns and replace the empty cells to the left with indentations.

For example, the structure in Excel:

```
| Category | Subcategory | Type | Name | Code | Variable | Note      |
|----------|-------------|------|------|------|----------|-----------|
| A        |             |      |      |      |          |           |
|          | A           | A    | One  | one  | one      | Something |
|          | B           | A    | One  | One  | One      | Something |
|          | C           | A    | One  | One  | One      | Something |
| B        |             |      |      |      |          |           |
|          | A           | A    | One  | One  | One      | Something |
|          |             | B    | One  | One  | One      | Something |
|          | B           | A    | One  | One  | One      | Something |
|          |             | B    | One  | One  | One      | Something |

(Edited to better represent the hierarchy)
```

To achieve this I followed the example here [Adding vertical hierarchy lines to a category column of a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195523/adding-vertical-hierarchy-lines-to-a-category-column-of-a-table), but this involved a lot of manual editing of the Latex table-code (which I generated from [TablesGenerator](http://tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables)) - thus making adding new contents to the table very tiresome.

This looks like the following:

[image: MWE]

Can the `pst-node`-package, or some other package, ease the process of this column-collapse?

That is, **without the manual editing of the table to create the indentation**. The `pst-node`-package code used in the answer to the linked question is a bit hard to fathom, but the result looks somewhat close to the MWE output above.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand{\lvl}{~~~}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{margin=0.25cm}
\begin{longtable}{p{5.5cm}p{6cm}p{2.5cm}p{4cm}}
\toprule
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Code} & \textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Note} \\
\midrule
Cat A & A & a &  \\
\lvl SubCat A & A_A1 & a_a1_all & Note \\
\lvl\lvl Type A & A_A1_A & a_a1 &  \\
\lvl\lvl\lvl Item A & A_A1_A_A & a_a1_a &  \\
\lvl\lvl\lvl Item B & A_A1_A_B & a_a1_b &  \\
\lvl SubCat B & A_B1 & a_b1_all & Note \\
\lvl\lvl Type B & A_B1_B & a_b1 &  \\
\lvl\lvl\lvl Item A & A_B1_A & a_b1_a &  \\
\lvl\lvl\lvl Item B & A_B1_B_B & b_a1_b &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\restoregeometry

\end{document}
```

## Solution

As it turned out in my case, given an initial table in Excel, the easiest way of doing this was in Excel itself. See [Collapse columns horizontally in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34694529/collapse-columns-horizontally-in-excel/34694943#34694943) on Stackoverflow for the solution.

Comment: What you would like to have is not quite clear to me. Could you post a (hand-)sketch of what the result should look like?

Comment: I composed a MWE and added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\SFii{\textcolor{red}{\textSFii\textSFx}}
\def\SFviii{\textcolor{red}{\textSFviii\textSFx}}
\def\SFx{\textcolor{red}{\textSFx}}
\def\SFxi{\textcolor{red}{\textSFxi}}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}    
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*3{>{\ttfamily}l} l}\toprule
\textrm{\emph{Name}} & \textrm{\emph{Code}} & \textrm{\emph{Variable}} & \emph{Note} 
\\\midrule
Cat A      & & & \\
\SFviii SubCat A       & A\_A1       & a\_a1\_all & Note \\
\SFxi~\SFii Type A     & A\_A1\_A    & a\_a1      &      \\
\SFxi~~~\SFviii Item A & A\_A1\_A\_A & a\_a1\_a   &      \\
\SFxi~~~\SFii Item B   & A\_A1\_A\_B & a\_a1\_b   &      \\
\SFii SubCat B         & A\_B1       & a\_b1\_all & Note \\
~~\SFii Type B         & A\_B1\_B    & a\_b1      &      \\
~~~~\SFviii Item A     & A\_B1\_A\_A & a\_b1\_a   &      \\
~~~~\SFii Item B       & A\_B1\_B\_B & b\_a1\_b   &      \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With package `newunicodechar` you can define the characters and use directly if they are present with your keyboard:

```
%\usepackage{newunicodechar}
%\newunicodechar{└}{\textSFii}
%\newunicodechar{├}{\textSFviii}
%\newunicodechar{─}{\textSFx}
%\newunicodechar{|}{\textSFxi}
```

Comment: Also a very good example of an implementation of the example-image I linked to initially, but as I had written below it what I am trying to solve is not the adding of lines between levels but rather collapsing the columns and adding indentation automatically - ie, not manually. I edited the question clarify this.

Comment: I accepted this as the answer because it was closest to what I was trying to achieve. However, in the end I did this in Excel, see [Collapse columns horizontally in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34694529/collapse-columns-horizontally-in-excel/34694943#34694943) for a method.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `pst-node`. The `\psDefBoxNodes{name}{text}` puts `text` in a box and defines 12 associated node: 3 on top ,  3 on the centre line, 3 on the base line and 3 on the bottom. The names of the nodes are `name:tl`, `ame:tC`, `name:tr`, &c. Then the relevant nodes are connected with a custom `\tconnect` command, which is a `\ncangle` command with suitable parameters:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand{\lvl}{\hskip1.667em}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\newcommand\tconnect[2]{\psset{angleA=-90, angleB=180, offsetA =4pt,%
offsetB=2pt}\ncangle{#1:bl}{#2:Bl}}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{margin=0.25cm}
\begin{postscript}\psset{linecolor=red, linewidth=0.5pt, nodesepA=1ex, nodesepB =0.5ex, linejoin=1}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
  \begin{tabular}{p{5.5cm}p{6cm}p{2.5cm}p{4cm}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Code} & \textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Note} \\
    \midrule
    \psDefBoxNodes{cA}{Cat A} & & & \\
    \lvl \psDefBoxNodes{scA}{SubCat A} & A_A1 & a_a1_all & Note \\
    \lvl\lvl \psDefBoxNodes{tA}{Type A} & A_A1_A & a_a1 & \\
    \lvl\lvl\lvl \psDefBoxNodes{iAA}{Item A} & A_A1_A_A & a_a1_a & \\
    \lvl\lvl\lvl \psDefBoxNodes{iAB}{Item B} & A_A1_A_B & a_a1_b & \\
    \lvl \psDefBoxNodes{scB}{SubCat B} & A_B1 & a_b1_all & Note \\
    \lvl\lvl \psDefBoxNodes{tB}{Type B} & A_B1_B & a_b1 & \\
    \lvl\lvl\lvl \psDefBoxNodes{iBA}{Item A} & A_B1_A & a_b1_a & \\
    \lvl\lvl\lvl \psDefBoxNodes{iBB}{Item B} & A_B1_B_B & b_a1_b & \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \psset{angleA=-90, angleB=180, offsetA =4pt, offsetB =2pt}
  \tconnect{cA}{scA}
  \tconnect{cA}{scB}
  \tconnect{scA}{tA}
  \tconnect{scB}{tB}
  \tconnect{tA}{iAA}
  \tconnect{tA}{iAB}
  \tconnect{tB}{iBA}
  \tconnect{tB}{iBB}

\end{postscript}
\restoregeometry

\end{document}
```

*Note:* I don't think this code could break across pages, so I replaced the `longtable` environment with a plain `tabular` one.

[image]

Comment: This very excellently creates an output like the example-image I linked to initially, but I think my explanation was a bit lacking. I replace that image with the output from the MWE, which is a better representation of it. I am still having the problem of how to create the indentation/collapsing the columns without manually editing the table though.